# I want to use on seeds a method that I use for tests on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, rspec-rails, seeding

I have this AuthorizationHelpers and I'm using on RSpec.

```
module AuthorizationHelpers
  def assign_role!(user, role, post)
    Role.where(user: user, post: post).delete_all
    Role.create!(user: user, role: role, post: post)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include AuthorizationHelpers
end
```

And now I want to use this method `assign_role!` on seeds.
like this:

```
Post.all.each do |post|
    [:manager, :editor, :viewer].each do |role|
      User.all.where(admin: false).each do |user|
          assign_role!(user, role, post)
      end
    end
  end
```

If I try to use this on rails console I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assign_role!' for main:Object
```

Has some way to use this on seeds? Or I need to do other thing?

Comment: When you call `assign_role!`, what object do you imagine you are calling `assign_role!` *on*?

Comment: this assign_role serves for add roles for users on a post.

Comment: The question isn't what the *purpose* is. The question is what *object* do you intend for this to be called on? Typically, when you call something, it looks like `Class.method` or `Module.method` or `@object.method`. But, what do you think is happening when you call a bare `assign_role!` (not called on a `Class` or `Module` or  `@object`). What object do you think this is being called on? (Hint: check the error you posted.)

Comment: It's for User.
I'm thinking to put this on a helper.

Comment: Yes! So, `assign_role!(user, role, post)` should be `user.assign_role!(user, role, post)`. But, `user` won't have the method `assign_role!` because... why??? (Hint: How does a module method become a method on an object?) And, if this is a method on `user`, then you shouldn't have to pass `user` here `user.assign_role!(user, role, post)` because you're calling the method on a the `user`.

Comment: the only way It does the role for a user is on user_controller by method
def build_roles_for(user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167374/discussion-between-jvillian-and-rld).

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the OP abandoned use of the module and did the following in `seeds.rb`:

```
unless Post.exists?(title: title)
post = Post.create!(...)
[:manager, :editor, :viewer].each do |role|
  if user = User.find_by_email("#{role}@newscity.com")
    user.roles.create(post: post, role: role)
  end
end
```

Check out the chat (in the original question comments) for the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not necessarily related to your question, but more about the semantics of your code.

First of all: why you don't define `assign_role!` as an instance method for your user model and you can use anywhere? Seems to be a reasonable place for that logic to be.

Second: seeds are supposed to be the minimal data for your application to work properly after a fresh installation. Usually it's an one-off command; to create data in specs consider using factories instead (a popular library is [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot)).

It feels unnatural for your code to invoke stuff defined in `spec` folder.

Comment: Hey, thank's for reply.
I already use FactoryGirl.
I will try what you told.